# Mashiach and the (blessing of the) tribes (Gen. 49)

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, commentaries, messiah, shevatim-12-tribes

I have a question regarding the blessings of the tribes in Bereishis 49. The Torah ([49:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.49.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) states for example, *"Issachar is a strong-boned ass, Crouching among the sheepfolds*", which Rashi explains as *"he bears the yoke of the Torah (i.e. obligations) like a strong ass upon which may be placed a heavy load"* (citing the Midrash: Bereishit Rabbah 99:9, note that the Shelah explains why Issachar is compared to a donkey, and not to a lion for example: Torah Shebikhtav, Vayechi, Derekh Chayim 24).

**The question is as follow: is there any commentary or a sefer that explains that each tribe, represents a certain aspect of Mashiach?**

Comment: Whilst Yissachar's prevailing attribute was one of talmud torah that doesn't mean other tribes were devoid of Torah study. Surely Rambam is just saying that Moshiach will be a good ben Torah. That doesn't mean he has to have roots in Yissachar?

Comment: Quite aside from the fact that there are numerous sources that point he will come from Dovid Hamelech....

Comment: Yeah exactly. I just made a connection to Yissachar as an illustration of my question. The question I was wondering about was if there is a deeper, hidden layer behind these blessings of the tribes, that refer to Mashiach. For example, is there a explanation that each tribe represents a certain aspect of Mashiach?

Comment: I really doubt it.

Comment: You would assume that since Yaakov sought to reveal the end of days to his sons when he blessed them, and since the *nusach* of Hashem Echad, which Rashi says alludes to the days of *mashiach* originated when the tribes stood around Yaakov's deathbed, that there is indeed a connection between his blessings and *mashiach*.